# Scroll - Div inside Div

Tags: css, html, overflow, parallax

I'm trying to put a scroll on a DIV inside another one.

So... the first div is a content like div. Just some margin, padding and position to put my content in a center column.

Inside this div, I want to put a text box with vertical scroll. So I'll put 800px height content inside a 400px height space, for example.

The scroll class:

```
.scrollbox {
   overflow-y: auto !important;
   /*background: blue !important;*/
   height: 800px;
   width:100%; 
       }
```

But its nothing happening.

Look: http://www.agenciarara.com.br/2013/marinheiros

Answer (score 0):

problem with scoll is in your paralax script, try out this part of code:

**CSS**

```
.scrollbox {
    position: relative;
    height: 400px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    z-index: 9999; /*higher than paralax */ 
}
```